# Send a post request through an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

I am starting to use a Payment API and I'm following [their jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/alaingoldman/cpxLp/5/). They are posting to the website [requestbin](http://requestb.in/) in the fiddle. However, how do I make it post to my server instead? I am using balanced payments, rails and HAML.

In the first line of code `var THEPOSTTOLINK = 'http://requestb.in/1hkphb71';` The example shows where to post to but how do I do that in Rails? I can't just write localhost:3000  or www.mysite.user/account.

Javascript

```
var THEPOSTTOLINK = 'http://requestb.in/1hkphb71';

var marketplaceUri = '/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MPg9bCIQUZMBoiPMnvWkQJW'; 
balanced.init(marketplaceUri);
function responseCallbackHandler(response) {
   switch (response.status) {
     case 400:
         console.log(response.error);
         break;
     case 404:
         console.log(response.error);
         break;
     case 201:
         var $form = $("#bank-account-form");
         var bank_account_uri = response.data['uri'];
         $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: bank_account_uri,
            name: 'balancedBankAccountURI'
         }).appendTo($form);
         $form.attr({action: THEPOSTTOLINK});
         $form.get(0).submit();
     }
 }
var tokenizeInstrument = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var $form = $('#bank-account-form');
     var bankAccountData = {
         name: $form.find('.ba-name').val(),
         account_number: $form.find('.ba-an').val(),
         bank_code: $form.find('.ba-rn').val(),
         type: $form.find('select').val()
     };
     balanced.bankAccount.create(bankAccountData, responseCallbackHandler);
 };
$('#bank-account-form').submit(tokenizeInstrument);
```

Bank account form

```
%form#bank-account-form{:action => "#", :method => "POST"}
  = label_tag :bank_name, "Account Holder's Name"
  = text_field_tag :bank_name, nil, name: nil, :value => "John Q. TaxPayer", class: "ba-name"
  %p
  = label_tag :route_num, "Routing Number"
  = text_field_tag :route_num, nil, name: nil, :value => "121000358", class: "ba-rn"
  %p
  = label_tag :acct_num, "Account Number"
  = text_field_tag :acct_num, nil, name: nil, :value => "9900000001", class: "ba-an"
  %p
  %button.btn{:type => "submit"}
    tokenize
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in #balanced on IRC, here's a rough example on how to accomplish what you're looking for. https://gist.github.com/remear/7f6d7e6f24aa7e63fd2b

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.